# How do you prevent a BehaviourSubject from being consumed before it's defined?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on a user service that keeps track of users by their user_id. It first checks if user_id is present in their cookies, if it isn't it makes a get request to the api to create a new one and returns the id in the response. My problem is that the user_id is being consumed before the response is completed. I have two questions:

1. The BehaviourSubject is being consumed before it's even defined as a new BehaviourService, components that consume it are calling .subscribe() on `undefined` as a result and the app is crashing.
2. Is the really necessary for me to subscribe to the user_id every single time I want to retrieve it? The code is turning into hell to work with since i'm subscribing to the behavioursubject first and then inside the subscribe method I'm writing my code. I can't figure out a better way to go about it, and from the texts I've read they mention that linking streams is the right approach, but this just feels very wrong.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing

## get ruid or create one - user.service.ts

```
constructor(...) {
    public ruid: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    if(!Cookies.get('ruid')) {
        this.http.get(url).subscribe(
            (value) => {
                this.ruid = new BehaviorSubject(value)
                Cookies.set('ruid', value)
            }
        )
    } else {
        this.ruid = new BehaviorSubject(Cookie.get('ruid'));
    }
}
```

## use ruid in component

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    data;
    this.userService.ruid.subscribe(
        (value) => {
            this.data = this.http.get(url + value).map(res => res.json())
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need here is to setup resolver on your route. See my example from real project below:

**resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LocationResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private  locationsApiService: LocationsApiService, private appStorage: AppStorage, private authService: AuthService) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            const sessionData = this.authService.getSessionData();

            if (!sessionData.Location) {
                this.locationsApiService.getUserLocations().subscribe(
                    locations => {
                        sessionData.Location = locations[0].Name;
                        sessionData.LocationId = locations[0].Id;

                        this.authService.updateSessionData(sessionData);
                        this.appStorage.set(AppConstants.storage.userLocations, locations);

                        observer.next(sessionData.LocationId);
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                );
            } else {
                observer.next(sessionData.LocationId);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
{
        path: 'app',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        resolve: {
            locationId: LocationResolver
        },
        children: [...]
}
```

Basically what it does is not resolving route up until it gets the necessary data. In my case I need to query locationId and provide it to every call after login. So resolver either looks for it in LocalStorage or doing a call to the API and then sets the location.

UPD: In your case you can put such resolver on the route that subscribes to BehaviorSubject and it will not get instantiated and subscribed until you finish all the API calls.

Comment: The problem is that a lot of services/components subscribe to the userService, and there isn't a single endpoint that clients would hit - for example the first route they ever target on the site could be `/item/:id` and the user logic that creates an id or broadcasts it would still need to be available.

Comment: You can put this on your root route. That way resolver will work for any endpoint on your website. But only initially, meaning if you will move through different routes it will not get called anymore, only on 1st page load.  However if it doesn't fit in your architecture, I apologize. This is just common solution for me for cases when I need to wait for some data from API before component instantiation.

Comment: No, this seems like a great solution and something that I've been looking for for some time (I read about app_initializer and a few other techniques), I'm just trying to gauge exactly how this would work. When you say root route, do you mean `/`, and if so, would that just apply the resolver if the user enters the `/` route directly or any route on the site since `/` is a "parent" of other routes?